# Zoom app on Mac leaves open an invisible Safari window

Tags: macos, safari, zoom-meeting

I am using the Zoom app on macOS Catalina for meetings.

I see there's a strange behaviour that happens. Even when I completely close Safari (quit) or when I restart the Mac, I still can see there is a silent window that stays open (see screenshot).

I call this window silent/invisible because when it's open, the window does not display anything at all, like nothing. This seems similar to a ghost process.

This is annoying because this breaks totally the user experience. Because this occurs, when I want to open Safari, I have to right-click on the button to open a new window, because the silent window is already open.

Is there any way to stop that app to open a silent window on Safari ?

[image: strange behaviour]

Answer (score 2):

Have you set Safari to restore your previously opened tabs/windows on startup, or to open a specific (home) page? If the former, go to Preferences and change that to any webpage you like, then restart Safari to see if this unwanted ghost windows is still there.

(It shouldn't)

If the latter, try uninstalling/reinstalling Zoom.

Comment: I verified, and indeed this setting was on. I managed to correct my problem another way (see answer). If the problem comes up again, I'll try your solution ! Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

It might be a bit overkill, but I tried this little AppleScript I found googling:

```
tell application "Safari"
   close every window
end tell
```

I launched it in the Script Editor app.

And it works pretty well. Did not see the window opening again.

Comment: The wonders you can perform with AppleScript... Good going, and smooth sailing...!